# android webView: can not open jquery-mobile popup

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview

android webView: can not open jquery-mobile popup. Tried the following:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

It did not help.

Tried webview debugging, no errors on console.

Jquery-mobile: 1.4.5, 
Android: minSdkVersion 24, targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: When you load your page in webview only the popup does not work?

Comment: popup and adding/showing new page by ajax.